# PropType for millisecond date in React

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Now I am using `PropTypes.number` for the date in a millisecond. is there any better option than this?

MillisecondDate: `1571596200000`

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! No, since this is a number, the `number` proptype is correct.

Comment: Okay...Thank you.